# Upload the image path into db and image in the folder name upload

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-form-helper

This is the controller:

```
public function category()
    {
        if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('admin/home');
        }
        else{
                $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $image_data=$_POST['file'];
            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
            {
                // no file uploaded or failed upload
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                $this->load->view('admin/home', $error);
            }
            else
            {
                // success
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                $this->your_upload_model->add($title, $description, $data["file_name"]);

                $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
            }
        }

    }
```

This is the view:

```
<?php echo validation_errors();?>
        <?php echo form_open_multipart('login/category');?>
        <?php
        if(isset($error))
        {
            echo $error;
        }
        ?>
<table>
<tr>
        <td align=right>Logo:</td>

        <td><input type="file" name="file"></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="submit"></td>

        </tr>

        </table>
```

I am getting two errors:

1. Message: Undefined index: file
2. You did not select a file to upload.

Even though textfield names are same and I used `form_open_multipart()`. Also, the image is not uploaded and the errors are not helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `$_POST['file']` won't work, but second, you need to supply the HTML field name in `do_upload()`:

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file'))
{
...
}
```

Also, remove `$image_data=$_POST['file'];` because it won't work anyway. You are already using `$this->upload->data()` which is the correct way to get uploaded file data.

The reason `$this->upload->do_upload()` does not work without the field name is because it looks for the field `name="userfile"` if the parameter is not supplied. You are using `name="file"`.

Comment: I have done the changes whatever u have done,errors have gone but image is not uploaded and errors are not displayed.Can u pls help this ....

Comment: I have created a folder name called uploads in the controller folder, but the image did not upload

Comment: Make sure the `$config['upload_path']` is a full path... you can use `$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . '/uploads/';`. `FCPATH` is a CI constant to get the path of the front controller (index.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for the first question :

```
public function category()
{
 if (array_key_exists('submit', $_POST)) {
  ---------You can enter the remaining code here............
 }
}
```

And for the second one:

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload("file"))
{
 -----------code here----------
}
```